# What Is The Default Magento Weight Unit And How Can Change It

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

I use Amasty Table Rate extension. I need to know in which weight measurement Magento is converting data.

Ans also from where I can change its default measurement unit.
I used gram, but I want to use KG - Kilo Gram for shipping.

So I need to change Magento weight measurement unit.
How can I do that, any setting is available in Magento Backend?

Answer (score 4):

Magento doesn't care for units regarding to weight, it's just a number.

The meaning depends on how you enter the data. If you entered/imported the weight in gram, you'll have to use gram in the table rates as well.

Comment: I was about to write the same thing, but then [I found this](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php#L294) in the DHL carrier model. Aparently DHL (and probably UPS and Fedex carriers) has a way of determining the weight. But for custom carriers I don't think there is a restriction unless Amasty implemented one.

Comment: @Marius interesting, I have to admit that I have no clue about the `Mage_Usa` module and don't know where these parameters come from.

Comment: me neither.  I'm still searching for it.

Comment: Anyone help me, i am using MatrixRate shipping, Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps matrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate.